# Как спарсить текст из тега если y нео нет класса? Python, библиотеки: bs4, requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Это часть кода сайта, нyжно спарсить слова: "**Гостиница Тархо**".

```
"<a href="/main/cities/makhachkala/gostinitsa_tarho.html" target="_blank" title="Тархо">Гостиница Тархо</a>
```

Comment: На странице не один такой тег `a` со значением атрибута `href` `"/main/cities/makhachkala/gostinitsa_tarho.html"`?

Comment: Значение атрибyта href всегда разное, так что один.

Comment: `title="Тархо"` тоже не уникально? Если нет, то находить, как относительный элемент чего-то постоянного.

Comment: Спасибо, долго мyчался.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте примерно так

```
`hotel=<a href="/main/cities/makhachkala/gostinitsa_tarho.html" target="_blank" title="Тархо">Гостиница Тархо</a`>

    get_text_hotel=soup.find("a", attrs={"target": "_blank"}).get_text
```

или

```
get_text_hotel=soup.find("a", attrs={"href": "/main/cities/makhachkala/gostinitsa_tarho.html"}).get_text
```

или

```
get_text_hotel=soup.find("a").get_text
```

Пробуйте разные варианты. Можно также попробовать через Xpath запросы, только для начала нужно импортировать библиотеку 'lxml'

Так примерно будет на lxml (не начало кода)

```
tree=<a href="/main/cities/makhachkala/gostinitsa_tarho.html" target="_blank" title="Тархо">Гостиница Тархо</a>

hotel=tree.xpath(.//a/text())
```